# Google app is crashing when trying to link Google Home with Tuya Smart life

Tags: applications, google-apps, google-home

I want to link Google Home with Tuya Smart Life, but when I click the accept prompt in the Tuya app, it shows "Google has stopped".

I tried removing the app and linking it with the browser, but it also showed an error. I also tried updating the Google app but it still crashes. Any help is appreciated.

Update: I updated my phone to Android 9 and Google is not crashing anymore at that point, but the agree link button in the Tuya app opens Google Home's home screen.

Comment: Make sure the Tuya device(s) have the latest firmware installed.

Comment: I can control them with the original Tuya app but i cant connect to google home as **google** crashes

Comment: Just to confirm, is this what you are trying to do? [Quick Guide of Using Google Home to Control Smart Devices](https://developer.tuya.com/en/docs/iot/googlehomeguide?id=K9j6yqpeqzzgp)

Comment: Yes. @AndrewT.  This is what I am trying to do.